# Confusion when trying to write a class

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

I'm writing my own class for a thesis... yes, yet another thesis class! XD

This class is based on the standard book class, but I don't want all options of the book class to be available when writing a thesis. **How could I achieve that?**

---

My confusion comes with the use of `LoadClass` with `\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOptions}` versus `LoadClassWithOptions`, I read their use in `clsguide` but I'm still off.

If someone can baby feed me the difference, and point me to some examples I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like

```
\DeclareOption*{% 
  \ClassWarning{mythesisclass}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption' ignored}%
}
```

before processing the options and loading the class. The warning is optional, but it's nice to let the user know that something is not being passed through in the usual way.

What this does is ignore all options that are not explicitly declared, so any options that you *do* want to be passed on must be defined with `\DeclareOption`.

Here's an example snippet from a class of mine:

```
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{10pt}{memoir}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{11pt}{memoir}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{memoir}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\PassOptionsToClass{final}{memoir}}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\PassOptionsToClass{draft}{memoir}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \ClassWarning{mugsthesis}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption' ignored}%
}
\ExecuteOptions{12pt,final} % defaults
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[letterpaper,oneside]{memoir} % options here are fixed; no changes allowed
```

Comment: @paul-gesser Your explanation was really helpful. Finally I'm cleaning my code XD because I did a lousy jobs the first time.